# How to get data from server in Nativescript gridview?

Tags: nativescript

I am able to load data from sqlServer using mat table in angular, but have no clue how to do same in nativescript?. I think GridView will work,but cant find source to load dynamic data.

Comment: you can use listview for the same.https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/list-view

Answer (score 0):

If GridLayout is what you mean by GridView, it's just layout not responsible for loading data.

If you are looking to load list of items on screen, then [ListView](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/listview) is what you need. If you like to show table kind of layout with multiple columns then you must design your item template with a GridLayout.

If you go with [RadListView](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/item-layouts), you have different layouting option too.